# Longest substring

Tags: python, string, algorithm, substring

```
s = 'abcabcbb'

def longsubstring(s):
  if len(s)==0:
  return 0
  list1 = []   
  empty = ''
  for i in s:
    if i in empty:
       list1.append(len(empty)) 
       empty = ''
       continue     
    else:
       empty+=i
 
 return max(list1) 


longsubstring(s)
```

The above code works fine when s = 'abcabcbb'
but it returns 1 when actually 2 for s = 'aab'. Could someone debug the code tell me where I am wrong to satisfy the condition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to find the largest substring without any repetition of consecutive letters?

Comment: Could you kindly mention what is your requirement from the program, what do you want it to perform

Comment: The longest substring of `'abcabcbb'` is `'abcabcbb'` unless there's some other condition on the substring. Might help to spell that out.

Comment: @Pawan `Could someone debug the code tell me where I am wrong` is not exactly what SO is for. Have tried the pen & paper dry run to see for yourself where you are getting stuck or making error?

Comment: Ok this is my first post, I am sorry for not being clearer. I have to find the longest substring without repetition consecutively. when s = 'abcabcbb' that means abc is the longest substring here since the 4th charater is already repeating. the max length here is 3. you can make that out of the code. when I put s = 'aab' here this code is not working because it should return ab's length but it is only giving the lenghth of a and then the loop stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modification to your code that worked

```
s = 'aab'

def longsubstring(s):
  if len(s)==0:
    return 0
  list1 = []   
  empty = ''
  for i in range(0,len(s)):
      empty=''

      for j in range(i,len(s)):
          
          if s[j] in empty:
              
              list1.append(len(empty)) 
              empty = ''
              break    
          else:
              empty+=s[j]
      list1.append(len(empty))
      
  return max(list1) 


print(longsubstring(s))
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked fine. I appreciate it. Though I was unclear with my question. You figured out with your sharpness.

Comment: I just tried to figure out what you are trying to do by looking at your code. Still, the code I posted had some minor error, like it will throw an error if you provide a single character input. I have made the changes, now it will work perfectly. Thanks.